# Angular date filter unexpectedly shifts 1 h

Tags: angularjs, timestamp

I have been using angular date filter to format my time stamp. But it seems it shifts my time stamp by 1 hour and I don't know how to control that.

2015-06-18T23:59:59Z was converted to 19-Jun-2015 00:59:59

I knew it is related to timezone but my time stamp had time zone specified. I don't want to hardcode a time zone in my filter because I don't want to update my application when UK summer/winter time changes.

Could someone advise me please?

Here's example:

http://jsfiddle.net/chfw/5vy5s1ey/1/

```
<div ng-app>
    2015-06-18T23:59:59Z was converted to  <font color=red> 
    {{"2015-06-18T23:59:59Z" | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure yet why, but if you change the date in the string from `2015-06-18T23:59:59Z` to `2015-06-18 23:59:59` (removed the T and Z) it will work as you expect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5vy5s1ey/2/

Comment: indeed, it works without 'T' and 'Z'.

Comment: It might be considering UTC time. I for instance saw it as 3 hours difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because 'T' and 'Z' refer to UTC timezone and the filter takes that into account and tries to make the necessary adjustments. Not sure entirely on the specifics.

Removing 'T' and 'Z' will treat it like a neutral timestamp and won't make any shifting:

```
{{"2015-06-18 23:59:59" | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vy5s1ey/2)